# In a Powershell, Win Forms GUI, is there a way to turn on/turn off certain events dynamically

Tags: winforms, powershell, events, onclicklistener, keyboard-events

I have a powershell script using Windows Forms to create the GUI. I want certain Controls to catch click and keystroke events **for a while**, then stop (ie. no longer need to monitor that event and/or call the event handler func).

I do not see functions like Remove_click() or Clear_Keypress() or similar to stop the call to the event_handler. (complement of Add_click() and Add_keypress() methods).

I was expecting to find a clear, reset, or remove equivalent method?
Or is there a way to remove the reference to the event handler function, such that the function is no longer called? Like, setting the func pointer to $null?

The creation code snippet looks something like this:

```
$someButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$someButton.Add_Click({c_eventHandler})
$form.Controls.Add($someButton)
$someBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$someBox.Add_KeyPress({kp_eventHandler})
$form.Controls.Add($someBox)
```

I was hoping there was something like:

```
$someBox.Remove_Keypress() or 
$someBox.Clear_Keypress()
```

Or some way to $null the event handler function pointer, so it would no longer be called.

Any help is so welcome. My searches have come up with zero reliable answers. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could create script-scoped or globally scoped boolean variables you can examine in the event handlers.

Start your code with this:

```
$processClick, $processKeyPress = $true
```

and change the handlers to:

```
$someButton.Add_Click({if ($script:processClick) {c_eventHandler}})
$someBox.Add_KeyPress({if ($script:processKeyPress) {kp_eventHandler}})
```

Next, at a certain point in time or depending on some condition, set one or both variables to `$false`

```
if ($theConditionToStopClickProcessing) { $script:processClick = $false }
```

Comment: So, are you saying that in order to turn off the Click or keypress event watch, I simply have to call the $control.Add_xxxxx() method with no arguments? Your example is unclear once an event_handler is set. Your 'if' statement is clear if this is the initial call and you either want to watch for an event or do not. My question relates to when the script is already watching for an event, can I stop it (and restart it if needed)?

Comment: @BentChainRing What I'm saying is, is that it would be very simple to have another event, like a timer, to set a variable depending on certain condition. The event can then check inside its scriptblock this variable and depending on that do one thing or someting else. Much more elegant then trying to set the event to $null I would think.

Comment: Thank you. My whole intent was to remove the calling of a function (the event_handler) when it is not needed anymore. Yes, I recognize that I could manage this process inside the event_handler, but my question was about if I add an event_handler, could I un-add it during the script execution.